# how create folder with data and add file and zip the folder

Tags: mv, zip

I need create folder with date and add some files into that folder and need to zip that folder. 
For example

I have directory called A which has files like
`pandi_yyyymmdd.csv, vino_YYYYMMDD.csv`

I need to create folder like `pandi_vino_YYYYMMDD` need to add above files into this folder

Finally I need to zip folder `pandi_vino_YYYYMMDD`

I tried like below `` zip -q  pandi_vino.`date +%Y%m%d`pandi.20200528.csv | mkdir pandi_vino.`date +%Y%m%d ``

Comment: Are you looking for a script to run on a huge set of files or a specific solution for just these two files? Does A only contain these two files, or more? If more, which of the files need to move into the newly created directory and how can your script identify them?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood

If you have to zip the whole A folder as pandi_vino:

```
FOLDER=pandi_vino_`date +%Y%m%d`; cp -r A $FOLDER && zip -r $FOLDER.zip $FOLDER
```

If you did mean anything else let me know,
first time here

Comment: Is there really no `zip` option to provide the name of the folder and then have `zip` do that for you? seems like an important feature.